# can not update facebook status message

Tags: python, facebook

i am using the following code to post status update to a users  profile in facebook but every time it just returns could not update what is wrong here ?

```
def fb_post_message(request):
    import urllib2
    try:
        urllib2.urlopen('https://graph.facebook.com/me/feed',"message='hello world'")
    except:
        return HttpResponse('could not submit')
    return HttpResponse('submitted');
```

Comment: please reformat your code so that it's readable

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If that is your actual code, and you haven't edited any sensitive information out, then you are not even authenticating to Facebook as a user. So, of course, it won't be able to submit the change.

I highly recommend using a library designed to interface with Facebook's APIs. For information on Python libraries that interface with Facebook, see the [User:Python](http://wiki.developers.facebook.com/index.php/User:Python) page on the Facebook Developer Wiki.

Answer (score 0):

You forgot to add access token in your request. [Read this comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3327244/facebook-wall-writing-application/5539949#5539949) for more code specific information.