# Facebook wall writing application

Tags: php, python, facebook

I was wondering if i could possible write an app, that could be a list of all my friends and just simply posting a message to their walls on the friends i select. Not a message, a wall post. So it appears that i went to their wall and wrote a message, they have no idea that an app is pushing the message to them.

also could it be written in python :) its what i know. php is so icky, but doable if it is the only option.

Please and thank you.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Check the Python SDK for the Facebook Graph API:

http://github.com/facebook/python-sdk

In particular, you want the `put_wall_post` function.

A short python script making use of this module should fit your needs perfectly.

Answer (score 4):

Check out the Facebook API. It will more than likely show that the wall post came from your application. As far as the language you implement in, I think you could use Python.

Answer (score 3):

There are a couple of Facebook APIs that could tie in to. I'm at work and any website that makes mention of facebook is blocked so I can't provide links, but Google 'Facebook API'.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, it is possible. The [facebook api](http://developers.facebook.com/) supports Python via [python-sdk](http://github.com/facebook/python-sdk). You would be interested in `stream.publish` ([link](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/rest/stream.publish))

Answer (score 3):

Sure, you could do this. You'll need to have a look at the [docs](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/).
You can use the [Python SDK](http://github.com/facebook/python-sdk/) to work in Python, and the [Graph API](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/api) to make the posts.  Have fun

Answer (score 2):

Here is below code to achieve your requirement in facebook application: (Your application should be already contain publish to wall permission. That you can find at [Start up Application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2690723/facebook-graph-api-and-django/5539531#5539531))

```
update_url = "https://graph.facebook.com/<Your_Friend_Facebook_ID>/feed"
form_fields = {
   "access_token": "Your Access Token",
   "message" : "Your Message"
}
temp = {}
for k, v in form_fields.iteritems():
  temp[k] = unicode(v).encode('utf-8')

form_data = urllib.urlencode(temp)
res = urlfetch.fetch(url=update_url,
                     payload=form_data,
                     method=urlfetch.POST,
                     headers={'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'})
result = json.loads(res.content)
if result.get('id', False):
   "Success"
else:
   "Failure"
```